# SB37 abend in production and can not change the space parameter

Tags: mainframe

My colleague faced an issue, where his sort job failed with an **SB37** abend, I know that this error can be rectified by allocating more space to the output file but my question here is:

How can I remediate an **SB37** abend without changing space allocation?

It takes a week or more to move changes to production.   As such, I can't change the space allocation of file at the moment as the error is in production.

Comment: **you can not**, you will need some JCL change

Comment: You use an override until the updated procedure is in place. Another thng: why was the possibility of exceeding the space allocation not monitored and fixed in advance?

Comment: How is the job executed?  Are you using CA-7, IBM Workload Scheduler or Control-M from BMC?   Each of those products should allow an override for the job assuming you are using a PROC.  Can you provide more detail on the job and your environment?

Comment: Can you provide the associated IEC030I message which will help identify possible remediations.

Comment: "IT takes a week or more to move changes to production" - Is this also the case for a programming-error that pays every customer $1000 per day? If not, then there must be some sort of fast track to production. If the issue is important enough it can go this road, if not - then it's not that important if it fails.

Comment: Is it a PDS? If it is and you can look at it in ISPF dataset list, you can do a compress and that may give you enough space to finish the job.

Answer (score 4):

An [**SB37**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieah700/m014723.htm) abend indicates an out of space condition during end-of-volume processing.

> B37    Explanation The error was detected by the end-of-volume
>   routine. This system completion code is accompanied by message
>   IEC030I. Refer to the explanation of message IEC030I for complete
>   information about the task that was ended and for an explanation of
>   the return code (rc in the message text) in register 15.

This is accompanied with message [**IEC030I**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieam700/m010590.htm) which will provide more information about the issue.

Depending on a few items your production control team may be able to fix the environment where it would allow the job to run.  Lacking more detail it is impossible to provide an exact answer so consider this a roadmap on how to approach the problem.

> IEC030I   **B37**-**rc**,mod, jjj,sss,ddname[-#],
>   dev,**ser**,diagcode,dsname(member)

In the message there should be a **volser** that identifes the volume that was being written to.  If you have the production control team look at the contents of that volume there may be insufficient space that can be remedied by removing datasets.  There are too many options to enumerate without specifics about the failure, type of dataset and other information to guide you.

However, as indicated in other comments, if you have a production control team that can run the job, they should be able to make changes to the JCL to direct the output dataset to another set of volumes or storage groups.

Changes to the JCL are likely the only way to correct the problem.